# Case mysql error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT count(*),
CASE count(*)
WHEN >=0 
then Esta vacio
end
FROM producto
```

Al poner esta consulta me sale el error

> ```
> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax
> ```

He estado leyendo por internet y no encuentro la solución a este problema

Comment: Hola bsg, qué intentas hacer?

Comment: contar productos y si esta vacio que salga "esta vacio"

Comment: Te he enviado una respuesta para que funcionen ambas cosas en un único campo con nombre.

Comment: @bsg, considera marcar como aceptada la de Oscar. le da mil vueltas a la mia ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La [sintaxis de `CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html#docs-body) que intentas usar es:

```sql
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Podemos diferenciar dos problemas en tu consulta SQL:

- Las cadenas de caracteres deben estar delimitadas correctamente (el texto `Está vacío` debe ir entre comillas simples).
- La sintaxis de `CASE` que quieres usar no permite `>=0` como valor de `when_value`.

Podrías haber usado una comprobación completa (`count(*)>=0`) pero su resultado hubiera sido comparado (`TRUE` es 1 y `FALSE` es 0) con el de `case_value`, provocando resultados inesperados (`count(*)>=0` **SIEMPRE** vale `TRUE` porque siempre será igual o superior a 0), por lo que siempre saldría `Está vacío` como resultado.

---

**SOLUCIÓN PROPUESTA:**

Si quieres obtener un listado manteniendo el número de registros encontrados en el `count(*)` y agregar el texto `Está vacío` sólo en los que tengan 0, entonces puedes hacer:

```sql
SELECT
  campo,
  CASE count(*)
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Está vacío'
    ELSE count(*)
  END CASE numero
FROM
  producto
GROUP BY
  campo
```

El `SELECT` funciona como siempre, el primer `campo` podría ser (opcionalmente) el campo por el que haces el `GROUP BY` de productos (*).

El segundo campo sería, dependiendo del valor de `count(*)` la cadena de caracteres `Está vacío` si la cuenta es `0` o bien `count(*)` en caso contrario. El nombre del campo se llamará `numero`.

---

**EJEMPLO MÁS COMPLETO:**

En este ejemplo se completa el contenido del campo `numero` incluyendo distinción de plural y singular.

```sql
SELECT
  campo,
  CASE count(*)
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Está vacío'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Hay 1 producto'
    ELSE CONCAT('Hay ', count(*), ' productos')
  END CASE numero
FROM
  producto
GROUP BY
  campo
```

---

(*) Si no quieres usar, o no usas, un `GROUP BY` en tu consulta, entonces puedes quitar tanto el campo en el `SELECT` como la cláusula `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE count(*)
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Está vacío'
    ELSE count(*)
  END CASE numero
FROM
  producto
```

Comment: oh si, se me olvidó mencionar su falta de comillas.

Comment: @bsg Debería ser esta la respuesta marcada como aceptada, por ser más clara y más completa.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya le avisé en los comentarios de su pregutna, donde el `@` si funciona. aqui no le llega la notificacion

Comment: Gracias a los dos. Lo importante es que haya conseguido hacer lo que él quería y que queden registradas ambas respuestas para futuras búsquedas y lecturas.

Answer (score 3):

La [sintaxis de CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) podria ser moviendo el `count(*)` detrás del `when`

Tambien te falta rodear el texto entre comillas `'` (gracias Oscar)

```
SELECT 
    count(*),
CASE 
    WHEN count(*) = 0  THEN 'está vacio' END 
FROM 
    producto
```

Comment: De nada (+1). Pero quita lo de que "la sintaxis correcta sería..." ya que, como puedes ver en mi ejemplo (y en el primero del enlace que proporcionas), la sintaxis que usó era correcta, pero el `WHEN` no, porque no se permiten rangos (`>=` en su caso en `when_value`) al no ser una comparación (`search_condition` en tu ejemplo, la segunda sintaxis permitida).